# Chrome downloading PDF instead of displaying

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, vue.js, pdf

I've following code running succesfully in production since last 3-4 years. (Vue.js)

```html
<object :data="pdfUrl" 
    type="application/pdf" 
    width="100%" height="100%" 
    style="min-height: 700px">
</object>
```

On clicking a button the modal window opens and displays PDF. However after latest chrome update `Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)` it is no longer showing the PDF in the modal but downloading instead.

I've tried different options with `<embed>` and `<iframe>` options but in all cases it just downloads showing empty modal window. Also installed Adobe Chrome Extension without any luck.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a Chrome setting, they probably changed the default in the new version.

Comment: I tried the settings here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en but its off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check and make sure the `.pdf` files are of the type `application/pdf`?

In my case, I had this when files where stored in Azure blobs with the type `application/octet-stream`.

This may help: [Azure Blob always downloads when navigating to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805944/azure-blob-always-downloads-when-navigating-to-url)

Comment: Yes it is using application/pdf.