# IE10 not playing a video when using the <video> tag, but plays it when requesting the video directly

Tags: html5-video, internet-explorer-10

I have a webpage with a  tag on it with the following markup:

```
<video width="456" height="360" controls autoplay>
    <source src="Movies/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="Movies/Intro_H264.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8.0, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="Movies/Intro_H264.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
</video>
```

If I visit this page in IE10 it renders the video player but with an error message that reads: **"Error: unsupported video type of invalid file path"**

But what's odd is if I right-click on the video box and choose, Copy video URL, and then open a new tab in IE and paste in the direct URL to the video file (`Movies/Intro.mp4`) it plays in the browser without issue.

Also, I can visit the page using Chrome and it plays the MP4 video from the webpage without issue. All that to say, I don't think there's any issue with the video file itself or the encoding, but why is IE 10 not playing the video when it's in the  tag, but it is playing it when requesting the video directly?

Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue, in my case the `Content-Type` was set correctly but it still won't play. Curiously, it does play in IE9. Any ideas?

Comment: I see this even on http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp where presumably the mime type is correct :-)

Answer (score 8):

I would check whether the mime-type is correctly being returned for the file.

Chrome will play correctly regardless of the MIME Type returned.

To check:

1. Press F12 to display the IE Tools Window/Pane.
2. Go to the Network Tab
3. Click Start Capturing
4. Browse to the page in question
5. Find the mp4 line
6. If the Type is displayed as application/octect-stream then this is your issue.

Comment: how to fix application/octet-streem then?

Comment: I see a blank type and in the result column it says (Aborted)

Comment: What should I expect to see? I see text/plain. (Which I assume is wrong)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with IE 11 and the problem was the content type was application/octect-stream as stated by  csmith. I was serving my videos from Azure storage and apparently that is the default content type.

You can change the type with Azure storage or using Azure api as shown in the post

[Set Content-type of media files stored on Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040403/set-content-type-of-media-files-stored-on-blob)

Here is a guide for people on Amazon cloud (I did not test it)

[Changing content type for Amazon](https://coderwall.com/p/ciap_a)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the web server to use MIME type video/mp4 for .mp4. I accidentally set .mp4 to use MIME type video/mpeg, the video plays in Chrome, but not in IE11.

Comment: Thank you! This was my problem also. Spent a couple hours trying to reformat the file before finding this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue which was a real pain in the ass. My solution was actually quite simple (after searching on the internet for about 4 hours).

Add this line (specific for IE) to your `.htaccess` file.

`AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v`

Answer (score 0):

When you paste the URL to your browser it doesn't use HTML5 player anymore, so it doesn't say that it is really a supported file; only that the file path should be valid.

According to wikipedia, IE10 supports (not only) H.264 for video and AAC for audio - these are very common formats for mp4 container. Chrome's support is much wider ([video-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support) and [audio-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio#Supported_audio_codecs)wise).

The problem is that the Intro.mp4 file might have different formats altogether (the file could by just renamed or created using unsupported formats).

I'd look into the file using properties->details or third party programs (for example Media Info).

I don't think it is IE10's issue. The only similar one I've found is when the user was  too specific using unsupported format of used codecs ([...] type='video/mp4; codecs="H.264, AAC"' [...]).

Answer (score 0):

Now it is very easy to update mime type for your videos on amazon s3,

Just login and navigate to your file, under preferences you will see metadata, there you can edit content-type

Save it and reload your page.

Answer (score 0):

If it directly plays find when you put the `.mp4` URL into the browser make sure it's not running with the Quicktime plugin which you may have installed (especially if you use iTunes). Right click on the successfully playing video to rule that out. If it comes up with menu items related to Quicktime you may want to disable Quicktime plugin in adins and continue troubleshooting.

Sample MP4 video: http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4