# Streaming Video in Sharepoint 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, video-streaming, html5-video, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to stream video in an html page on an extranet which uses Sharepoint 3.0 (which I think is also considered 2007?). I'm using the HTML5 video tag with a flash fall back. The video plays in Chrome and Firefox but will not play in any version of IE. In IE10 I get the error message "Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path". Is there anything that I can do to get the video to play in IE on Sharepoint 3.0?

Here is my current code, I currently don't have the ogv version since IE doesn't support that format anyway and that's the browser I'm having trouble with:

```
<video poster="poster.jpg" controls="" preload="none" width="640" height="360">
    <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="my-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="//flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" width="640" height="360">
        <param name="movie" value="//flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="controls=true&amp;poster=poster.jpg&amp;src=my-video.mp4" />
    </object>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the mp4 mime type to IIS. Using the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500282/ie10-not-playing-a-video-when-using-the-video-tag-but-plays-it-when-requestin/19498602#19498602), I was able to determine that the correct mime type was not being returned for the mp4 file.