# Azure Logic Apps - Get Blob Content - Setting Content type

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, content-type, azure-logic-apps

The Azure Logic Apps action "Get Blob Content" doesn't allow us to set the return content-type.

By default, it returns the blob as binary (octet-stream), which is useless in most cases.  In general it would be useful to have text (e.g. json, xml, csv, etc.).

I know the action is in beta.  Is that on the short term roadmap?

Comment: Have you tried setting the blob to the correct content-type? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040403/set-content-type-of-media-files-stored-on-blob

Comment: Yes.  The blob was /json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling much with Logic Apps, I finally understood what was going on.

The JSON output from the HTTP request is the JSON representation of an XML payload:

```
{
  "$content-type": "application/xml",
  "$content": "77u/PD94bWwgdm..."
}
```

So we can decode it, but it is useless really.  That is an XML object for Logic App.  We can apply xml functions to it, such as xpath.

Answer (score 8):

So I had a blob sitting in az storage with json in it.
Fetching blob got me a octet back that was pretty useless, as I was unable to parse it.

> BadRequest. The property 'content' must be of type JSON in the
>   'ParseJson' action inputs, but was of type 'application/octet-stream'.

So I setup an "Initialize variable", content type of string, pointing to GetBlobContent->File Content.  The base64 conversion occurs under the hood and I am now able to access my json via the variable.

No code required.

**JSON OUTPUT...**

[image]

**FLOW, NO CODE...**

[image]

Enjoy!  Healy in Tampa...

Answer (score 7):

Workaround I found is to use the Logic App expression base64ToString.

For instance, create an action of type "Compose" (Data Operations group) with the following code:

```
        "ComposeToString": {
            "inputs": "@base64ToString(body('Get_blob_content').$content)",
            "runAfter": {
                "Get_blob_content": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Compose"
        }
```

The output will be the text representation of the blob.

Comment: thanks that was progressing. i was able to parse it but not able to put that parsed in to a slack message.

Comment: I am getting the results as 'click to download' link as it is reading the ftp into a binary. Could not find a way to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

1. You would need to know the content-type.
2. Use @{body('Get_blob_content')['$content']} to get the content part alone.

Answer (score 0):

Is enough to "Initialize Variable" and take the output of the Get Blob Content as type "String". This will automatically parse the content:

[image: parsing blob content by initializing a variable of String type]