# Azure blob storage conversion from octect-stream (binary)

Tags: azure, binary, cloud, blob

I've a storage account on azure, this storage contain two files by folder

1) a file DATA.bin with my data in **binary**(like Uint, float, float..)

2) a file log.txt with some parameters for these data (computation)

Someone know an azure service to read these data in binary and convert in csv ?

Comment: You can use azure storage sdk to access the files. But converting to csv has to be a custom implementation on your end.

Comment: @Baskar Thank you for your answer, but in reality I have to find the best service to perform a task every time I have binary files that arrive with its log.

I've seen the service azure function (function app), and other systems, I have to program it in C# I'm looking for the best possible solution and the best for the perenniality of the application.
If you have any ideas, I'm interested.

Comment: This thread suggest some options to convert binary to string using Logic Apps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598188/azure-logic-apps-get-blob-content-setting-content-type