# How to create html table from blob json in Azure Logic App

Tags: json, html-table, azure-logic-apps

Hi I would like to create html tabe in Azure Logic App.
I have data loaded from blob via Blob connector (Get blob content using path) 
[image: app flow]
I used Compose connector based on answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598188/azure-logic-apps-get-blob-content-setting-content-type)
But I get error -

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Create_HTML_table' inputs at line '1' and column '1747': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value '﻿[{"ServiceName":"routingsf","SubServiceName":"roadinfo/supportedmaps","ErrorType":"System.AggregateException","ErrorMessage":"One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)","Count":4} ]' cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ﻿. Path '', line 0, position 0.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json for usage details.'.
```

Code of Compose and Create HTML table connector is like :

```
"Compose": {
            "inputs": "@base64ToString(body('Get_blob_content_using_path').$content)",
            "runAfter": {
                "Get_blob_content_using_path_2": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Compose"
        },
        "Create_HTML_table": {
            "inputs": {
                "format": "HTML",
                "from": "@json(outputs('Compose'))"
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Compose": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Table"
        },
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try my way to create table. After get the content, use the **Parse JSON** , the content input `json(body('Get_blob_content_using_path'))`, the Scheme choose `Use sample payload to generate schema` and just copy and paste your json file content.

[image]

Then create HTML table , the From choose the expression `array(body('Parse_JSON'))`.

Here is the Logic flow and my result.

[image]

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other questions, please let me know.

**Update: I copy your json content tomy json file and test again. And It works.**

[image]

**So please make sure you logic app flow is right. Or you could share you flow.**

**Make sure these two steps are right:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this is not working for me. My json file content is array - `[{"ServiceName":"routingsf","SubServiceName":"distancematrix","ErrorType":"System.AggregateException","ErrorMessage":"One or more errors occurred. (Graph: v13/ta.2018.03_v900/irn/irn_car_overlay.fastest.xml.gz does not exist!)","Count":3}
]` and I getting error in parsing json -

Comment: Problem is with file in my opinion. My file is generated by copy activity from Data Factory. When I create json file on my PC and uploaded it on blob storade, all works fine.
But When I try process generated file by DF, I get error described in question from Parse operation. - [link](https://imgur.com/a/hRtcLtW)

Comment: Did you mean you could parse Json with the blob using content, but couldn't parse Json from uploaded Json. And what's the detail about getting data from uploaded Json.

Comment: And did you create your action "Parse Json" with my way.

Comment: @Tomáš Čičman , any more questions? If it's helpful, you could accept it as the answer.Thanks!