# how to convert a BLOB object (audio) in a normal audio like .mp3 or .wav for update to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, jsx

I want update An audio recorded with the microphone to my firebase database
, but I get an BLOB object and I take the url like this blob:http://localhost:3000/b890eafb-2265-458e-a9d8-84b81657d7fb but if I want play this audio in other computer not heard.

And the only thing I can think of is to convert it to .mp3 or .wav and upload it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Content-type of media files stored on Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040403/set-content-type-of-media-files-stored-on-blob)

Answer (score -3):

You will have to convert your blob URL to mp3 file and upload it on to the cloud. The following code converts blob URL to mp3.

```
var file = {};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', blobURL, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        file.file = this.response;
        file.name = "whatever_filename.mp3";
        file.size = getYourBlobSize();
        file.type = "audio/mpeg";
        uploadAudioBlobs(file);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Where does `uploadAudioBlobs` come from?

Comment: @BartS Implementation is yours.