# MVC 4 File Download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download, mime-types

Here is my code I tried following way to put functionality for download a file but it doesn't work properly. It doesn't show save file dialog.

```
 protected virtual FileResult Download(string FileName, string FilePath)
 {

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", FileName.Length.ToString());
        return File(FilePath, "application/exe", FileName);
 }
```

And tried this way also:

```
protected virtual ActionResult Download(string FileName, string FilePath)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", FileName.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application//x-unknown";
    Response.WriteFile(FilePath.Replace("\\", "/"));
     Response.Flush();
    Response.End(); 
}
```

But both are not working. What I missing?

Comment: I hope you are Aware about the security Problems your filepath and filename variables come along with...

Comment: Filename length != Content length. Also, its likely browsers are blocking the executable download. I know my IE does.. and Chrome throws up a "are you absolutely sure?" Prompt.

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult

Comment: I tried with .doc file also and from same location it works well for exe file in asp.net.

Comment: This may be because of file compression (default I believe). Text works because the browser knows how to uncompress the files. Binary files (PDF, DOCX, etc.) compressed still look like binary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know major difference but following code is working fine for me for any file..May be because of ContentType as per @Garath suggest.

```
var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(oFullPath);
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", yourfilename));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
            Response.WriteFile(oFullPath);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct mimitype for exe file is `application/octet-stream` not `application/exe` or `application//x-unknown` - [check MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx)
You could look here for more definitions: [Get MIME type from filename extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-mime-type-from-filename-extension)

Comment: I get all things right but problem is that only txt files are download perfactly but doc files or pdf files are download but in corrupted format.