# Cant upload files using loopback Storage component REST API in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using loopback Storage component REST API in Xamarin to finish a file uploading job. However, it does not work and does not return any exceptions to me.

Here is my code:

library using: RestSharp.portable

```
public async Task addFiles(string name, byte[] file)
{
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient(App.StrongLoopAPI);
                var request = new RestRequest("containers/container1/upload", HttpMethod.Post);
                request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
                request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
                request.AddFile("file", file, name + ".jpg", System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data"));

                var res = await client.Execute(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //return null;
            }
}
```

Does my function have any problems?

Comment: have you tried using a 3rd party REST Client like Postman to verify your API is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the Content Type (Mime Type) wrong.

`AddFile` accepts as the last parameter the Content Type (for example `image/jpeg` for a JPG image), where you're using `multipart/form-data`.

There are different ways to figure out the Content Type of a file, see here:

[Get MIME type from filename extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-mime-type-from-filename-extension)

This should fix your issue.