# What is the correct mimetype for .tex-files?

Tags: mime-types

My webservice generates and returns a .tex-file. I want to give the correct mimetype in the http-header.

I didn't found so much except for [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/), where I find `application/x-tex`. Is this an authority to stick to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393525/11683

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those who came here... i ended up with
`"application/x-tex"`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `/etc/mime.types`, I found:

| MIME type | File extensions |
| --- | --- |
| `application/x-latex` | `latex` |
| `text/x-tex` | `tex`, `ltx`, `sty`, `cls` |