# Should I Be Using BlobContainerClient or BlobClient or Both?

Tags: c#, azure

I am getting confused with the C# azure sdk.

What I am trying to achieve.

Upload files from my computer to a folder in azure.

For example

Locally

```
MyFiles 
   -- Folder1
     -- file.txt
     -- img.jpg
   -- Folder2
      -- file2.json
      -- test.png
```

Azure Result

```
Container
     MyFiles 
           -- Folder1
             -- file.txt
             -- img.jpg
           -- Folder2
              -- file2.json
              -- test.png
```

So I want in my container on azure same file structure.

how I am doing it is

```
var sasCred = new AzureSasCrdentials("sasurl");
var container = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri("containerUrl"), sasCred);

var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("MyFilesFolderPath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach(var file in files)
{
   var cloudFilePath = file.Replace("MyFilesFolderPath", string.Empty);
   var fullPath= $"MyFiles{cloudFilePath};

  using(var s = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file))
  {
     await container.UploadBlobAsync(fullPath,stream); 
  }
}
```

This seems to do what I need it to do though I noticed the file type is something like "file octet stream" instead of .json/.png/txt or whatever it should be.

When I search it talks about using BlobCLient to set the file type but now I am sure if I should be using BlobContainerClient or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the ContentType property of the BlobHttpHeaders class as the desired content type.

There are also nuget libraries to get the mime type from the file name extension if they vary by upload.

```
blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "text/plain" });
```

Comment: I don't see SetBlobProperties as an option on BlobContainerClient. I have the Azure.Storage.Blobs vs 12.14.1.

Comment: do you have a nuget package to recommend for mime types that works with .net core?

Comment: Look here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108040/838023

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use both `BlobContainerClient` and `BlobClient` in this case. The way you would do it is that you would create an instance of `BlobClient` ([`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) specifically) using `BlobContainerClient` and blob name and use [`UploadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-specialized-blockblobclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) method there.

Your code (untested) would be something like:

```
var sasCred = new AzureSasCrdentials("sasurl");
var container = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri("containerUrl"), sasCred);

var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("MyFilesFolderPath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach(var file in files)
{
   var cloudFilePath = file.Replace("MyFilesFolderPath", string.Empty);
   var fullPath= $"MyFiles{cloudFilePath};

  using (var s = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file))
  {
      var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobClient(fullPath);//Get BlockBlobClient instance
      var blobContentType = GetContentTypeFromFileSomehow(file);//Write a helper method to get the content type
      var headers = new BlobHttpHeaders() { ContentType = blobContentType};//Set content type header for blob.
      var blobUploadOptions = new BlobUploadOptions() { HttpHeaders = headers};
      await blockBlob.UploadAsync(s, blobUploadOptions);//Upload blob 
  }
}
```